# Mac OS Catalina won't find my android LG KV20

Tags: android, macos, lg

I am trying to develop an app and test it on my android device, however my computer can't seem to find the device. On the phone developer mode is unlocked, usb debug is enabled, and usb configuration is set to MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). I have android studio installed on my mac and with the device plugged in running `adb devices` returns that there are not devices attached???

Comment: In my case restart my phone and Android Studio is the solution

Comment: @PaoloColombo I have tried that, but it hasn't seemed to fix the problem.